# Safest / Simplest way to secure iphone api webservice

Tags: java, ios, web-services, hash, authorization

I've been doing a lot of research and trying to figure out the best (most simple) way to secure an iphone app's webservice. My ideas so far are below:

1. Use oAuth 2.0 (cons: labor intensive)
2. Store salted&hashed password (SHA-1) and send each api call with username and salted password as url params
3. store salted&hashed password (SHA-1) with username and send both as one single url param that would be stored in the DB in a unique field or table
4. only allow users to log in via twitter login or facebook login.

Would any of these approaches work? Im leaning towards #3 right now because it seems simple yet effective in my eyes. Any feedback would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use 4. and implement OpenID. There is great support for it and it gives you Google Authentication as well as Yahoo and many others. It means your users no longer have to create accounts with you so you'll be able to retain customers more easily.